# What lines are required to fire (simulate / open) an event?

Tags: jquery, mobile, triggers, html5-canvas, hammer.js

So, look at [this example](http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/) and just click any of the buttons and see the sidebar appear.

I'm using `Hammer.js` to fire Javascript actions based upon touch actions. I want to open the sidebar with a swipe, but thus far, I'm not creating a working piece of code.

Simply `$('[data-effect="st-effect-2"]').trigger('click');` isn't sufficient. Atleast, Not on my mobile (iPad / Google Nexus 5).

So easy simulating a click on a button, doesn't work on mobile devices. So I'm looking for the 'back-end' code, which I can apply to my hammer.js swipe event. Take a look at [This script](http://pastebin.com/W2Fcu2Mk), for the Javascript needed for opening the sidebar. (Or check out [the same example](http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/) stated at the beginning).

Go ahead and play with [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8nQk/2/) and your touch devices (since it isn't working correctly on touch devices, so you can verify). Instead of swiping (preventing difficulty), I've changed the 'event' to 'tap', so simply tap on the document to fire any lines

Comment: I don't know Hammer.js... but I use jQuery Mobile for those things. See here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/

Comment: It's not the information about Hammer.js I need, but the execution code from the sidebar plugin, which I can't find.  But thanks

Comment: Your pastebins expire in 4 days.  Do you think you could incorporate the key parts of the code into your question?